# check if value changed upon change() trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed that change() can be triggered for a `<select>` even if the option was not changed.

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emMx6/) example.

Changing the selection will change the text input displayed. However (and I do know it's a bit of stretch) if you:

- select the drop down by clicking on its label `Selection:`
- press down on the keyboard (assuming `Show A` was selected)
- then select `Show A` with the mouse pointer it will trigger change().

Is there an easy workaround for this (right now I'm thinking of using a variable to keep track what the last selection was upon change())?

**EDIT:**
It seems it is a Chrome-specific problem. I was able to *fix* the problem by using a variable to keep track of what the last selected item was. I guess this a bug left for the jQuery/Chrome developers.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that in FF 6, in which browser are you experiencing this behavior?

Comment: @Niko chrome 14.0.835. Just saw that I can't reproduce it on IE 8 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the current value as data on the element (rather than a variable) like this:

```
$('#variable').data('currentval', $('#variable').val()).change(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.data('currentval') != t.val()) {        
        $(this).data('currentval', $(this).val());
        $('#listA').toggle('fast');
        $('#listB').toggle('fast');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emMx6/2/

Comment: Classy. I was not even aware of the data() feature.